# Cursor location not updated when non-focused EditText clicked

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext, cursor-position

When non-focused EditText clicked, it becomes focused, but cursor does not move to new location. I should click it again to move cursor to a new position.

**Q:** How can I focus and move cursor with only one click?

Answer (score 2):

I spent quite some time battling the same problem, and this is what I did:

In your layout xml, enable focusable and focusableInTouchMode

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
</LinearLayout>
```

Otherwise, whenever the softkeyboard comes up, it automatically scrolls to the front of the EditText. You can modify the position by overriding "OnFocusChangeListener" but it's a little ugly to poll the clicked position every time. I'm going to stick with the change above.